# Why am I getting an error about String not defined?

Tags: python, redis

I'm using the redis object mapper, and when I try to run this code:

```
from redis import *
from rom import util
from rom import *

util.set_connection_settings(host='localhost', db=7)
class User(Model):
    uName=String(required=True)
    password=String(required=True)
    thisId=(random.random()*100)


user=User(uName='pfleet',password='pass')
user.save()
#todo, save session ID
user2=User.get_by(uName='pfleet')
```

For some reason, when I run this code, I get an error that says 'Name String not defined', even though I typed the code in the same way as the online example on the ROM(redis object mapper) github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the @univerio's comment, it appears that `String` is imported by `from rom import *` only on python2.x, quote from the [docstring](https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/blob/master/rom/columns.py#L326):

```
note:: this column type is only available in Python 2.x
```

For python3.x you need to use `Text` instead.

```
class User(Model):
    uName=Text(required=True)
    password=Text(required=True)
```

As a side note, try not to use `from xxx import *` wildcard imports - it's really [a bad practice](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use
>   case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal
>   interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure
>   Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an
>   optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be
>   overwritten isn't known in advance).

Comment: The `String` column is [auto-imported](https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/blob/master/rom/__init__.py#L163) into the `rom` module *when on python 2.x* so `from rom import *` should import it, so I think OP is running python 3, in which case he should use `Text` instead.